# To notify an adapter from any activity, is this possible?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I've an activity A, which has a custom adapter class ADAPTER1. On clicking a button in ADAPTER1, the page is re-directed to activity B. From there if I'm clicking on button, for example: consider the like button in Facebook, the like status should be updated in the ADAPTER1 class also (i.e) to call notfiyDataChanged() from activity B.

Can anyone tell is this possible????

Comment: try  adapter.notfiyDataChanged()

Comment: can you please brief your answer?

Comment: How you get the list data ? from where ?

Comment: if you have adapter object in activity then it is possible if you have adapter object then use adapter.notfiyDataChanged()

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708882/how-to-update-listview-after-onresume-from-other-activity

Comment: In Activity A you have a ListView and touching a listview item. it shows detail of that item in next activity and like action from detail screen (Activity B) will update that item in adapter. is it right? this is what i got from your question

Comment: @umerk44, s exactly what I mentioned!

Comment: you can launch the activity B (on selecting the list item) using startActivityForResult and then once you selecting like button (what ever action ) then send the result back. Process the result returned at onActivityResult method and then you can update the list item (note you use list item position to update the values or the index of the item).